# Transferring an existing C# and ASP.NET Web Form site to Bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, powershell

So I have an existing page that's running ASP.NET and C# in order to display a front-end for some PowerShell commands. This was all developed in the community/free version of Visual Studio 2017.

Pseudo-code is below

```
User browses to page in browser
Browser presents lists of buttons and text fields
User inputs options into fields and clicks a button
C# runs in backend to run a PowerShell command doing various things, dumping into a JSON file the results
C# returns the results to the page by reading the JSON and turning it into a C# object, displaying as a C# Table
```

What I have already is that page (and sub pages for different features), displaying results to a simple table or div and displaying the buttons and text fields using the default C# table and some custom HTML to display the JSON properly.

What I want though, is to be able to port those features and functions to a Boostrap template, so I can take advantage of the handy dropdown menus, fancy buttons, etc. that are provided by Boostrap. Specifically I'm looking at using **Flatkit**.

All of the examples I've seen have either been for MVC stuff, starts entirely from scratch, or uses very simplistic Hello World examples, neither of which help when tackling this task as my code is web form based and more complex than an About page.

**So my question(s) is/are**

a) How can I create ASP.NET controls that will both play nicely with Bootstrap and feed data back into the C# file for processing? Something that can duplicate an `<asp:Button>` essentially, without refreshing the page entirely.

b) How can I then create another control or similar element on the front-end side to display that information? I'm using a simple `<asp:Table>` currently

I have the backend PowerShell and most of the logic written, I just need to know how I can make it interact nicely with Bootstrap essentially.

Web dev is not my usual forte , so a lot of the tutorials feel like reading Ancient Greek as they assume I know JQuery, Angular, DOM, etc. So if there's knowledge I'm lacking to make this work, links would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

End of day, Bootstrap or any `CSS` framework applies styles to HTML elements. `ASP.Net Web Forms Controls` render "vanilla" HTML - though some can be unwieldy (like `<form>` `input` `name` and `id` attributes - re: ASP.net uses the same value).

They can be styled as needed. Look into [`CssClass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass(v=vs.110).aspx)

Hth.